# Azure Storage Javascript SDK 12 function for listing blobs is failing

Tags: javascript, azure, blob, storage

I am using the [@azure/storage-blob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript/basic.js) version 12 SDK in my Javascript project and using the following syntax to get a list of blobs from a container. The following code results in the error `Cannot read property 'blobItems' of undefined`:

```
var i = 1;
  for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
    console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
  }
```

`containerClient` is defined and is being used successfully with other operations like uploading blobs etc.
Incidentally, I have successfully listed my blobs from the same container and using the same SAS token in a node.JS project using the same @azure/storage-blob package.

Comment: What you do mean Javascript project? Is that you run the script in the browser with html file?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Azure rest api](https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list) rather than the @azure/storage-blob library to obtain the list of blobs.

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list
```